# How to add vary custom header

Tags: nginx, apache-2.4, cache, varnish, http-headers

My application is changing the content based on user country code. Please find server request flow diagram.

> https request -> nginx handle the ssl termination -> varnish -> if not cacheed, get contents from apache
>
> http rquest -> varnish -> redirect to https link -> nginx handle the ssl termination -> varnish -> if not cached get contents from apache

Using varnish GeoIP module I found the user country code and set value to the header `req.http.X-Country-Code` I read this header value in the application.

**Problem:** It always caches the first hit and serves to all the locations

I hope adding vary header will resolve my problem, could you please guide me?

I'm not sure where to add vary header nginx or apache.

Answer (score 1):

Solution 1 )
https://varnish-cache.org/docs/5.1/users-guide/vcl-hashing.html

Solution 2 ) add the header vary

The vary header must be generated by the origin, because only the origin know which pages will change .

https://varnish-cache.org/docs/5.1/users-guide/increasing-your-hitrate.html?highlight=vary#http-vary

**if you can not add the header** at the origin , you can modify **vcl_backend_response** to add a Vary header

Some documentations :

https://varnish-cache.org/docs/5.1/reference/states.html#reference-states
https://varnish-cache.org/docs/5.1/users-guide/vcl-built-in-subs.html